# Bootstrap DateTimePicker set hour (09:00 - 20:00)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, smalot-datetimepicker

I'm using [smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

How can I set the range of the hour from `09:00` to `20:00` or disable the other hour.

I found the [trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) can set the hourmax and hourmin,
but how can i do in the bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Comment: i think you need to write your own logic for it..or you can validate it on change or blur event of datepicker..

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this is [not possible](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/38) using [smalot](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker)'s datetimepicker.

However, this *is* possible with [eonasdan's (closely related) datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). With eonasdan's plugin, you would use the parameter [**`en/disabledHours`**](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#endisabledhours):

```
$("#myPicker").datetimepicker({
    disabledHours: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 21, 22, 23, 24];
});
```